# Using expression browser /graph with prom-client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, prometheus

I am trying to use the `/graph` endpoint for the **Prometheus** expression browser, but I am not sure how to configure it.  I have `/metric` working, but since I don't have an endpoint for `/graph` I am trying to find how to set it up.  I thought it was built into **Prometheus** but haven't found examples on how to use it with **node.js**.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What do you need node.js for? Do you have a working application from which Prometheus can scrape metrics? This article in the documentation provides a good example on how to get started in Prometheus https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/getting_started/#starting-up-some-sample-targets

Comment: Well I feel dumb now, I am reporting metrics and send them to a prom server, its just not hosted by me.  I am just on the client side, not the prom server.  I need to get access to the prom server.  Thanks for you time, I will close the question.

Comment: No need to feel dumb ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Prom-Client is just that client to send stats from, not the Prometheus server. To access the data you need to access the server, not the client endpoints.  Sorry for the question.